# Wordpress Automattic AMP add_post_meta()

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I am using `Wordpress Automattic AMP plugin`. I have meta tags in my temp. How can I add these fields to amp single.php?

It does not look like this.

```
<? php echo get_post_meta ($ post-> ID, "field_name", true); ?>
```

In the AMP plugin, it shows the fields as follows;

```
<? php echo $ this-> get ('post_amp_content'); ?>
```

Could you help with this?

Comment: You can try looking in this [github post](https://github.com/Automattic/amp-wp/blob/develop/back-compat/templates-v0-3/single.php) for how to implement that in single.php. Also you can refer [here](https://www.webcodegeeks.com/wordpress/wordpress-get_post_meta-example/) for some example of custom field's meta. Hope this references helps.